# Android Studio 3.6 always select the first build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, build-variant

I've just updated to Android Studio 3.6 stable version. After that, every time I open my project. The Android Studio changes my selected build variant to the first item in the variant list. Then I have to change the selected variant and sync gradle again. :(

Anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug [you may want to report](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs)

Comment: same here, having multiple modules in app is a nightmare (and recompilation times are much much longer)

Comment: I have the same problem. I can compile through command line the intended variant, but not from the Interface the picker simply refuse to change build variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can mark the flavor that you use regularly as default:

```
flavor {
        isDefault.set(true)
        ...
}
```

This way the IDE will pick this flavor when it starts, instead of relying on the alphabetical order.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I think it is problem of upgrading android studio from version <= 3.5

My solution for this is to push your project to any VCS. Then you clone it as a new project and use android studio to open it. You will find the build variant is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I add the advice of @Hicham in both productFlavors which I want to be default. In this case, when I press "Re-import with defaults" in Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1, it resets to this one, instead of the first build variant in the list.

```
flavorDimensions = ["app", "version"]
productFlavors {
    setting {
        dimension "app"
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.1.1"
        isDefault.set(true)
        buildConfigField 'String', 'END_URL', '"/setting/"'
    }
    space {
        dimension "app"
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.8"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'END_URL', '"/space/"'
    }
    list {
        dimension "app"
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.8"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'END_URL', '"/list/"'
    }
    product {
        dimension "version"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'MAIN_URL', '"https://..."'
        isDefault.set(true)
    }
    test {
        dimension "version"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'MAIN_URL', '"https://..."'
    }
}
```

[image: Re-import with defaults]